# Mysqli select statement prepared statement with value insert

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to use php prepared statements to select the username and password from the database. When I run it from the database it works when i run SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username ='user' AND Password ='password' LIMIT 1. When the browser runs it it gives to many parameters.

```
    private function authenticate()
{

    $query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username =?
              AND Password =?
              LIMIT 1";

    //prepare query and execute
    if(!$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query))
    {

        print "Failed to prepare statement";

    }

    else
    {

        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $this->username, $this->password);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);

        $stmt->store_result();

        $stmt->fetch();


        if($stmt->num_rows > 0) 
        {

            $this->status = 'Logged In';
            $this->setSessions();

        }

        else
        {

            $this->status = 'Not Logged In';

        }

    }    

    $stmt->close();


echo json_encode(array($this->status));

}
```

Comment: "run from the database" huh? You mean from the server command line or something?

Comment: it's not very clear, I totally misread this. Do you mean that when you run this query in let's say phpmyadmin, or mySQL workbench - it works fine, but when you try to run it off your script it fails?

Comment: yes i use mysql workbench and it runs fine